Compute $Spec(\mathbb{Z}_{(p)})\times_{\mathbb{Z}}Spec(\mathbb{Z}_{(q)})\cong Spec(\mathbb{Q})$
Let $p$, $q$ be two different prime numbers. Now want to compute fiber products as below:
$Spec(\mathbb{Z}_{(p)})\times_{\mathbb{Z}}Spec(\mathbb{Z}_{(q)})\cong Spec(\mathbb{Q})$
$Z_{(p)}$ is discrete valuation ring. And I'm kind of knowing that it's possible to compute as like $Spec(\mathbb{Z}_{(p)}\otimes_{\mathbb{Z}} \mathbb{Z}_{(q)})$. However, I'm not sure if it has some theory from commutative algebra, i.e. perhaps residue field, ideals from some propositions from classic commutative algebra text.
Can anyone helps me out, please?
I need an answer from a way of theoretically solving it by possibly using reference from a classical text of commutative algebra.

The product of affine schemes is the spectrum of the tensor product, so the question is equivalent to the ring-theory question of whether
$$
\mathbb{Z}_{(p)} \otimes_{\mathbb{Z}} \mathbb{Z}_{(q)} = \mathbb{Q}.
$$
This is true. The inclusion of the DVRs into $\mathbb{Q}$ gives us a natural map, which is surjective since we can write any rational number as a product of a number whose denominator is coprime to $p$ and a number whose denominator is coprime to $q$ (here we use $p \neq q$).
For injectivity, consider a sum of simple tensors
$$
\sum_i \frac{a_i}{b_i} \otimes \frac{c_i}{d_i},
$$
where $b_i$ is coprime to $p$ and $d_i$ is coprime to $q$.
Claim: any such sum of simple tensors can be written as a pure tensor
$$
\frac{1}{q^N} \otimes \frac{c}{d}.
$$
For each $b_i$, write $b_i = q^{N_i} \widetilde{b_i}$ where $\widetilde{b_i}$ is coprime to $q$. Then
$$
\frac{a_i}{b_i} \otimes \frac{c_i}{d_i} = \frac{a_i}{b_i} \otimes \frac{c_i\widetilde{b_i}}{d_i\widetilde{b_i}} =\frac{1}{q^{N_i}} \otimes \frac{a_ic_i}{d_i\widetilde{b_i}},
$$
and so we may assume each term is of the form $\frac{1}{q^{N_i}} \otimes \frac{c_i}{d_i}$.
We can use a similar trick to reduce the number of terms in the sum to one: to combine two terms with different values of $N_i$, use
\begin{align*}
\frac{1}{q^N} \otimes \frac{c_1}{d_1} + \frac{1}{q^M} \otimes \frac{c_2}{d_2} &= \frac{q^{M-N}}{q^M}  \otimes \frac{c_1}{d_1} + \frac{1}{q^M} \otimes \frac{c_2}{d_2}  \\ &= \frac{1}{q^M}  \otimes \frac{c_1(q^{M-N})}{d_1} + \frac{1}{q^M} \otimes \frac{c_2}{d_2} \\ &= \frac{1}{q^M} \otimes ( \frac{c_1(q^{M-N})}{d_1} + \frac{c_2}{d_2} ),
\end{align*}
where we have assumed $M > N$.
Once we know every tensor is of this form, injectivity is straightforward, since
$$
\frac{1}{q^N} \otimes \frac{c}{d} \mapsto \frac{c}{dq^N}
$$
which is zero if and only if $c = 0$, in which case the original tensor was $0$.
